# react-native-fs.the actual document directory path in android

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, react-native-fs

I tried the code for creating a file, and i created two files, and that is

```
    // require the module
    var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

    // create a path you want to write to
    var path = RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/test.txt';

    // write the file
    RNFS.writeFile(path, 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet', 'utf8')
    .then((success) => {
    console.log('FILE WRITTEN!');
    })
    .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
    });
```

i created two files with that code. but i cant see the actual created files. Where exactly it was saved?

Comment: Can you try changing the constant,  `var path = RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath + '/test.txt';`

Comment: Ohh. This paths looks familiar :D Thanks for the suggestion @HSBP i had a hint on where does it go

Comment: But where does the `DocumentDirectoryPath` saves to?

Answer (score 7):

You can't see them on your phone.
If you want to store files that you can see then use ExternalDirectoryPath or ExternalStorageDirectoryPath. I was also looking for an answer to a similar question but couldn't find any. So, I tried all these paths. My guess is DocumentDirectoryPath is used to store private data for your app. I am fairly new to Android development so take my words with grain of salt.